# DFSR alternative for Workgroups

Tags: file-synchronization

I use Distributed File System Replication (DFSR) for bidirectional file synchronization in my organization. This works a treat for anything in the domain. Now I'm dealing with a couple DMZ boxes that need the same kind of behavior and I'm at a loss as to how to handle it.

I specifically need include the following features:

- Constant monitoring / syncing, assuming the network is up
- Handling file deletion on either side - should remove both copies
- Preferably transfers files over SMB / CIFS.

What should I look at if I have two workgroup systems that need this kind of behavior? I've seen *tons* of products but nothing quite meeting my needs.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but is https://www.powerfolder.com/ something for you?